# SQLite to replace fopen()

Tags: sqlite, fopen

I have recently heard that SQLite is designed to replace fopen() ([1](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-05/what-i-learned-about-sqlite-at-a-postgresql-conference), [2](http://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/attachments/319_PGCon2014OpeningKeynote.pdf)) and hence it is faster to read or write a file from disk in some cases by using SQLite rather than fopen(). Could anyone explain what might cause it? I am assuming SQLite does not use RAM.

Comment: Have you try to validate by yourself both options instead of trusting to somebody else?

Comment: SQLite can open it's own files, but it's certainly not a replacement for fopen for other files, nor should you do fopen on a SQLite file and expect to get anything meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't quite "get" what Richard Hipp means by that statement. Of course under the hood SQLite will also use the `fopen(3)` system call, so it can not be any faster. But rather than opening a raw file (e.g. with `fopen`) and implementing your own structure and access functions (therefore ending up implementing a NIH DB at some point), you are better off by just using the SQLite API which is already optimized to death and will therefore probably faster than anything you come up with in a reasonable time.

Of course this applies only when your persisted data structures have a certain complexity. For simple files like text files you're certainly still better off with `fopen`.